# Can I create multiple items in one Fluid form?

Tags: typo3, fluid, extbase

I have following relations in my model: Request 1:n Hall (one-to-many)

In Request model class I have

```
/**
 * hall
 *
 * @var \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\ObjectStorage<\Vendor\Ext\Domain\Model\Hall>
 * @cascade remove
 */
protected $hall = null;
```

In Hall model class I have

```
/**
 * num
 *
 * @var string
 * @validate NotEmpty
 */
protected $num = '';
```

Can I set multiple items in one Fluid form? Like

```
<f:form avction="create" name="hall" object="{hall}" controller="Hall">
<f:form.textfield name="hall[num][]"  class="form-control" />
<f:form.textfield name="hall[num][]"  class="form-control" />   
<f:form.submit value="Create" />
</f:form>
```

Comment: Yes it is possible but you will need to allow the creating of subobjects in the initializeAction (s) by using the Propertymapper. Here is a quite good german tutorial about it (hope you can translate it for you) https://www.typo3lexikon.de/typo3-tutorials/core/systemextensions/extbase/property-mapper.html

To the end the creation of subobjects is explained very good.

Answer (score 2):

You are close to the solution, the field `name` you wrote is missing the proper plugin namespace however. There is an easier solution for this:

```
<f:form action="create" name="request" object="{request}" controller="Request">
    <f:form.textfield property="hall.0.num" class="form-control"/>
    <f:form.textfield property="hall.1.num" class="form-control"/>
    <f:form.submit value="Create"/>
</f:form>
```

It is essential that you create your root entity (*request* here) with the form and all relations through appropriate form fields. Using `property` ensures the proper name (including plugin namespace) for all fields, in this case e.g. `name="tx_myext_myplugin[request][hall][0][num]"`.

As you probably noticed you can add as many relation objects as desired as long as you use a numeric index for each object. For many fields you could use the `f:for` viewhelper.

Comment: Does this approach also work for *updating* several objects at once? I try to update the "description" field for several file references "images", assigned to an object "person". Like <f:form.textfield property="images.{itr.index}.originalResource.title" class="form-control" />

Comment: Yes, this also works, but you may need to add a hidden field with `property="images.{itr.index}" value="{root.images.{itr.index}}"`. This will lead to an `__identity` field being outputted which can then be used to update the correct related entity.

Comment: Thx, this principially works, too. At least for "direct" properties of a file reference like `<f:form.textfield property="images.{itr.index}.pid" />`. But when writing properties of a file references "original resource" like `<f:form.textfield property="images.{itr.index}.originalResource.title" />` this doesn not work.

Answer (score 0):

I personally struggle with the automapping of typo3 so I would do the following:

add the following funcs to your model

```
public function addHall(Hall $hall){
 $this->hall->atach($hall)
}

pubflic function removeHall(Hall $hall){
 $this->hall->detach($hall)
}
```

Note: Kepp in mind that you have to declare $hall al object storage

Now you can create a new hall object in your controller, persist the new hall, add it with the addHall-method to yor desired model and persist.

Hint: there are nice little functions fpr persisting; similar to PersistanceManager::persistAll() or s.th. like that